# What could cause known good libraries to suddenly throw errors? [ESP8266/Arduino IDE]

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino-esp8266

In trying to create a program that reads from a 4x4 matrix keypad that sends HTTP GET requests from a local server based on which key is pressed, I've encountered the following compilation errors. I've used these same libraries successfully before, and I don't think I've really changed anything since then.
[Using ESP8266 NodeMCU v3 module, programming via Arduino IDE]

```
In file included from C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-370583BB0D9E467723E0BFBE6D37A087\sketch\Jan11.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\cores\esp8266/Arduino.h:45:14: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
   45 | #define HIGH 0x1
      |              ^~~
c:\Users\jacob\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad\src/Keypad.h:56:16: note: in expansion of macro 'HIGH'
   56 | #define CLOSED HIGH
      |                ^~~~
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/tcpbase.h:57:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CLOSED'
   57 |   CLOSED      = 0,
      |   ^~~~~~
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\cores\esp8266/Arduino.h:45:14: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
   45 | #define HIGH 0x1
      |              ^~~
c:\Users\jacob\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad\src/Keypad.h:56:16: note: in expansion of macro 'HIGH'
   56 | #define CLOSED HIGH
      |                ^~~~
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/tcpbase.h:57:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CLOSED'
   57 |   CLOSED      = 0,
      |   ^~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\cores\esp8266/wl_definitions.h:73,
                 from C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:28,
                 from C:\Users\jacob\Documents\Arduino\Jan11\Jan11.ino:2:
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/tcpbase.h:56:16: note: to match this '{'
   56 | enum tcp_state {
      |                ^
In file included from C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-370583BB0D9E467723E0BFBE6D37A087\sketch\Jan11.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\cores\esp8266/Arduino.h:45:14: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
   45 | #define HIGH 0x1
      |              ^~~
c:\Users\jacob\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad\src/Keypad.h:56:16: note: in expansion of macro 'HIGH'
   56 | #define CLOSED HIGH
      |                ^~~~
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0/tools/sdk/lwip2/include/lwip/tcpbase.h:57:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CLOSED'
   57 |   CLOSED      = 0,
      |   ^~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\jacob\Documents\Arduino\Jan11\Jan11.ino:2:
C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.1.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:29:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
   29 | }
      | ^

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

What could cause this? Could I be using a function wrong that causes the compiler to expect something else inside these libraries?
Any recommended fixes?

I've tried reinstalling a handful of libraries, but nothing I've done has changed these messages showing up.

Comment: you updated esp8266 Arduino package

Comment: Check your code, you are likely has a missing `;` or `{`, `}` somewhere in your code.

Comment: "What could cause known good libraries to suddenly throw errors?" *The way you use it.*   But since we do not see any of your code, we can't tell you what you're doing wrong, As a wild guess: you should avoid redefining constants that are defined in a library that is known to be good.

Answer (score 0):

include the libraries afresh. that will work.